# How to display drop down list on gridcell image in gridview?

Tags: android, gridview, drop-down-menu

I need to show the drop down dialog on grid cell image when long press on the gridview image. That dialog wont exceed the image. That dialog must be inside of that image.
If there is any ways means please share with me.

Thank you

Comment: add an invisible view on the grid item, which looks like the dropdown you expect. Show it on long press, hide it on an item selection in the dropdown..

Comment: can you please post the code if any related to that

Comment: No. But i can help you understand what i said if you ask a specific question.